# Как убрать определённый символ из строки кроме её начала?

Tags: sql, oracle

Мне надо убрать дефис из середины чтобы остался только первый.

```
Select ('-SUPER-MAN') from dual
```

Желаемый резултат: `"-SUPERMAN"`

Comment: а если в строке более одного дефиса, и например дефис на конце строки, тоже надо убирать?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен. Если "убрать дефис из середины чтобы остался только первый", верно, то принятый вами ответ не правильный. Там будут убраны все дефисы и не только с середины.   Поправте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select regexp_REPLACE('-SUPER-MAN', '-', '', 2) from dual;
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

```
with sample as (select '-SUPER-MAN' str from dual) 
SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1,INSTR(str ,'-', -1)-1)|| SUBSTR(str,INSTR(str ,'-', 1, 2)+1)  as ciorticika
FROM sample;
```